# retaining order of columns after pivot

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a N x 3 DataFrame called A that looks like this:

```
   _Segment _Article  Binaire
0       550  5568226        1
1       550  5612047        1
2       550  5909228        1
3       550  5924375        1
4       550  5924456        1
5       550  6096557        1
....
```

The variable _Article is uniquely defined in A (there are N unique values of _Article in A).

I do a pivot:

```
B=A.pivot(index='_Segment', columns='_Article')
```

,then replace missing values nan with zeros:

```
B[np.isnan(B)]=0
```

and get:

```
          Binaire                                                        \
_Article  2332299  2332329  2332337  2932377  2968223  3195643  3346080   
_Segment                                                                  
550             0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
551             0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
552             0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
553             1        1        1        0        0        0        1   
554             0        0        0        1        0        1        0
```

where columns were sorted lexicographically during the pivot.

My question is: how do I retain the sort order of _Article in A in the columns of B? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. This works:

First, store the column _Article

```
order_art=A['_Article']
```

In the pivot, add the "values" argument to avoid hierarchical columns (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html), which prevent reindex to work properly:

```
B=A.pivot(index='_Segment', columns='_Article', values='_Binaire')
```

then, as before, replace nan's with zeros

```
B[np.isnan(B)]=0
```

and finally use reindex to restore the original order of variable _Article across columns:

```
B=B.reindex(columns=order_art)
```

Are there more elegant solutions?